# Isolation voltage spec in transformer

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, isolation, specifications

Could you please help me understanding this transformer spec?

I am planning to use [HCTSM80101AAL](https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/hctsm8.pdf) transformer and I would like to make sure that I am referencing the proper specification for voltage isolation capability between primary and secondary side of transformer. Hi-Pot test is just to use as a guideline for short transient as I understand.

Where is the continuous isolation voltage limit in this spec?

I believe level of insulation spec is about working voltage level on each leg (i.e., primary 1-2 or 2-3 or secondary 6-5 or 6-4). Please correct me if I my understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would like to make sure that I am referencing the proper
> specification for voltage isolation capability between primary and
> secondary side of transformer.*

and

> *Where is the continuous isolation voltage limit in this spec?*

The working isolation voltage is there on the front page of the [data sheet](https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/hctsm8.pdf): -

[image]

> *what's the highest peak or rms voltage I can apply across each
> inductor*

The transformer is designed to interface with the [SN6505B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn6505b.pdf?ts=1709398625726&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fen-us%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Den-US%2526searchTerm%253Dsn6505%2526nr%253D379). It runs at 420 kHz and an upper limit of supply voltage of 5 volts DC. Thus, the SN6505B limits the maximum voltage across the full primary to 10 volts p-p. Note that the E*T limit for the transformer is 11 \$\text{volt}\cdot\mu s\$ and that ties in nicely with the SN6505B's limits (when you do the math).

Comment: oh I understood that parameter as working voltage across each inductors.. is that the isolation voltage between primary and secondary? Then what's the highest peak or rms voltage I can apply across each inductors?

Comment: @AliaSana 800 volts RMS (1000 volts peak)  is the working voltage for the isolation barrier between primary and secondary. The highest voltage you can apply to the primary inductor is determined by switching frequency and energy transfer requirements (note that this isn't your primary question). Note also that the transformer is: **Designed for isolation power supplies using TI SN6501 and SN6505B** and that will certainly limit the voltage you can apply across the primary.